# Text file writing from arraylist object using FileWriter class

Tags: java, swing, io

It is working fine but i need to write the data line by line. I get one data from arraylis object and want to write in signal line into text file. second object should come in next line.

```
public void writeFile() {
    FileWriter writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new FileWriter("E:/AutomationToolWorkplace/AutomationTool/Test/ExpectedOutputHomescreenModule1.txt");
        for (String str : MP_result_set) {
            System.out.println("");
            writer.write(str);
        }
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Transciever.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Transciever.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{"data":
{"shared":false,
"port":"4096",
"packageName":"",
"installed":false,
"lock":false,
"like":false,
"type":"HomeScreen",
"ip":"192.168.1.24",
"screenId":"9999",
"selected":false,
"category":"",
"servicetype":"",
"price":"",
"subscribe":false,
"event":false,
"subtype":"Recommended",
"predefined":false,
"pricingmodel":"PPC",
"packageSelected":false}}

{"data":{
"port":"4096",
"screenId":"2050",
"result":"failure",
"recordList":[],
"reminderList":[],
"msg":"No record",
"playList":[],
"ip":"192.168.1.24"}}

{"data":{
"port":"4096",
"screenId":"12105",
"result":"success",
"list":["music","Action","Romance","Horror","Comedy","Thriller","Mystery","Drama"],
"type":"genre",
"ip":"192.168.1.24"}}
```

Comment: Why the Swing tag? Your question as stated contains no Swing code?

Comment: `MP_result_set` is an `ArrayList<String>`? Just to clarify, you want to write in your file every `{"data" ... ]` in separate lines, isn't?, in that case use `writer.write(str + "\n")` instead;

Answer (score 1):

You can simply append a "\n" to each string that you write, or use a [PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html)

> Prints formatted representations of objects to a text-output stream.

The simplest solution is to make use of [Apache Commons IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#writeLines%28java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.Writer%29) and the IOUtils.writeLines() method, which takes a collection and a writer. It avoids the need for you to perform the iteration yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
writer.write(str + "\n");
```

Comment: Do Michael's solution. Looks clean.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
System.out.println("");
```

with this:

```
writer.write("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

To write statements line-by-line wrap a [BuffererdWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) around your `FileWriter` and use `newLine()`

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path));
bw.write(str);
bw.newLine();
```

---

As noted by Piovezan, you should also remove the `System.out.println("")` as it only prints a linebreak to your stdout and not your file.

Comment: you could try adding a  `bw.flush();` before you close the writer to ensure all lines are written to the file